# cakephp .po files not being used

Tags: php, cakephp, localization, internationalization, cakephp-2.3

I'm trying to get CakePHP's [i18n component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html) to work. I have extracted my strings to `app/Locale/default.pot` using the i18n console task. I then copied it into `app/Locale/eng/LC_MESSAGES/default.po` and `app/Locale/fra/LC_MESSAGES/default.po` making sure to change the extension. I used the program Virtaal (similar to Poedit) to translate some of the strings.

In my app/Config/core.php I have set my default language to english with `Configure::write('Config.language', 'eng');` if I change it to `Configure::write('Config.language', 'fra');` I expected to see the new translated strings but nothing changed. I tried setting the Config.language key in the session as well but it didn't do anything. Printing out the configure value and session values I can see they are being set.

Am I missing something here? also in the many different posts I've been reading about i18n in CakePHP I've seen the key `fre` being used interchangeably with `fra` is there a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Common-Tasks-With-CakePHP/Internationalization-Localization.html it should be `fre` for french.

```
// locale path
/app/locale/fre/LC_MESSAGES/default.po (French)

// To change or set the language for your application, all you need to do is the following:
Configure::write('Config.language', 'fre');

// To set the language for the current user, store the setting in the Session object, like this:
$this->Session->write('Config.language', 'fre');
```

Further than that:
In our cakePHP application I have to restart the apache webserver after changing the files to get the new strings because of caching. Perhaps you have to do that too, but I'm not quite sure as we generate .mo files out of the .po via an POEdit setting. I dont't think you are forced to do this, because the cookboke doesn't say anything about that (or I didn't found it now :D ).

edit:
Looks like cake is using the `bibliographic` codes for french but the `terminology` for german. That's very confusing :/ : http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I tried changing all `fra`'s to `fre`'s and restarting apache but it's still not working.

Comment: Did you also renamed the path to `fre`?

Comment: Yes I did.. I not sure why but it's working now. I deleted everything in my app/Locale folder and added `Configure::write('Config.language', 'fra'); to my AppController's `beforeFilter()`.. I also switched back to `fra` apparently they can be used as synonyms. After running with Configure::write in my before filter once I removed it and it is still working so I'm really not sure what was wrong.

Comment: As of CakePHP v2.3 the code/folder name needs to be "fra" prior to that it needs to be "fre".